# Setting the flex values to make the label appear correctly when container width is small?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following form the label along the left column is sized correctly until there is not enough room. Then the labels shrink. But when the row has 3 items in it the label is sized different than the row with 2 items.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.input1 {
  flex: 1;
}
.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}
span {
  width: 120px;
}
.main {
  width: 200px;
}
.group {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

.shrinkSameAmount {
  width: 52px;
  min-width: 52px;
}
```

```html
<p>Full Size:</p>

<div class="group">
  <div class="row"><span>ID</span><input class="input1"/></div>
  <div class="row"><span>ID</span><input class="input1"/><button>X</button></div>
</div>

<p>Reduced Size:</p>

<div class="main group">
  <div class="row"><span>ID</span><input class="input1"/></div>
  <div class="row"><span>ID</span><input class="input1"/><button>X</button></div>
</div>


<p>What I want when reduced:</p>

<div class="main group">
  <div class="row"><span class="shrinkSameAmount">ID</span><input class="input1"/></div>
  <div class="row"><span class="shrinkSameAmount">ID</span><input class="input1"/><button>X</button></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can keep the label widths to the same size whether the width of the viewport is large or small?

Comment: `flex-shrink:0` or `min-width` instead of `width`?

Comment: or `min-width:0` to the input element?

Comment: @TemaniAfif `min-width` keeps them the same size at the set width. I'd like to keep the label widths the same when they shrink.

Comment: So you want the label width to be 120px even when the viewport shrinks? Can you explain if you mean something else.

Comment: @Adrift I updated my post. I like that the label width shrinks but it shrinks at different  amounts if the amount of items in the row is different. I'd like the label to shrink at the same rate.

Answer (score 2):

First add `min-width:0` to the input and button element to allow them to shrink. Then you can adjust the `flex-basis` to make sure that the input alone or the button and the input will have the same value.

In the example below the value is `300px`. If the input is alone it will take all this as its `flex-basis`. With the button, the value will be splitted between both

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.input1 {
  min-width: 0;
  flex-basis: 210px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.input1:last-child {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

button:last-child {
  flex-basis: 90px;
  max-width: 90px;
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 1px 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  flex-basis: 120px;
}

.group {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  width: 100%;
  animation: change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
    width: 18%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Full Size:</p>

<div class="group">
  <div class="row"><span>ID</span><input class="input1" /></div>
  <div class="row"><span>ID</span><input class="input1" /><button>X</button></div>
</div>
```

<sup>There is a slight miss alignment at low width, I will figured it out.</sup>

Comment: Nicely done, but is the `min-width: 0;` necessary on the button?

Comment: @Adrift probably not in this case since the content is only one character but it's always safe to add it and avoid potential issue

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox applies certain flexibility you need to control in this case. I changed your `<span>`s into `<label>` elements, and added this CSS:

```
label {
  flex: 0 0 120px;
}
```

The `flex` value here is shorthand for `flex-grow: 0`, `flex-shrink: 0`, `flex-basis: 120px`. The flex-basis property is a starting width, set it to whatever value you would like that "column" of labels to be.

To get the fields to obey the width of the container I changed the rule for the inputs to:

```
.input1 {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

This makes the inputs use up all available space.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
label {
  flex: 0 0 120px;
}
.input1 {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.main {
  width: 200px;
}
.group {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
```

```html
<p>Full Size:</p>

<div class="group">
  <div class="row"><label>ID</label><input class="input1"/></div>
  <div class="row"><label>ID</label><input class="input1"/><button>X</button></div>
</div>

<p>Reduced Size:</p>

<div class="main group">
  <div class="row"><label>ID</label><input class="input1"/></div>
  <div class="row"><label>ID</label><input class="input1"/><button>X</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Button is now outside `div.row` though.